# Is there Ruby on Rails framework in Redmine 1.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine

I am fresher to Redmine and Ruby on Rails.
I want to install Redmine 1.3.
Should I have to install  Ruby on Rails framework or it is by default present in Redmine 1.3

Comment: Reading the Redmine installation documentation would answer this question for you.

Answer (score 2):

Each Redmine release (the tar.gz and zip packages) includes Rails by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developer and are you going to install development environment then you should have to install ruby but if you are using production environment then doesn't necessary.